# Do I lose my War Chest if I temporarily leave my clan and go back?

Tags: clash-royale

I have to leave my clan in order to participate in another clan tournament.

Will I lose the current war chest I have, even if I go back an hour later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have a try today !

Leaving your clan during a season **doesn't result the lost of your war chest**.

However, if you have left the clan during a collect day, you can't do the battles.